# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/security/cert/internal/x509/X509V1CertImpl exception in Java 17.0.5

Tags: java

In Java 17.0.5, **com.sun.security.cert.internal.x509.X509V1CertImpl** has been removed.
And if I call X509Certificate.getInst() with X509Provider=null,
than **className = "com.sun.security.cert.internal.x509.X509V1CertImpl"**
and in the lower part it call **Class<?> certClass = Class.forName(className);** and end up

**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/security/cert/internal/x509/X509V1CertImpl**

```
private static final X509Certificate getInst(Object value) throws CertificateException {
        String className = X509Provider;
        if (className == null || className.isEmpty()) {
            className = "com.sun.security.cert.internal.x509.X509V1CertImpl";
        }

        try {
            Class<?>[] params = null;
            if (value instanceof InputStream) {
                params = new Class[]{InputStream.class};
            } else {
                if (!(value instanceof byte[])) {
                    throw new CertificateException("Unsupported argument type");
                }

                params = new Class[]{value.getClass()};
            }

            Class<?> certClass = Class.forName(className);
            Constructor<?> cons = certClass.getConstructor(params);
            Object obj = cons.newInstance(value);
            return (X509Certificate)obj;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException var6) {
            throw new CertificateException("Could not find class: " + var6);
```

Is this a bug for Java 17.0.5?

Comment: any of the com.sun.* classes are internal implementation details and should not be used directly. This has always been the case. They can and do (sometimes) change names or disappear entirely between even minor releases. Not a but in the standard library at all, rather you risking your neck doing something the documentation clearly states you should be wary of.

Answer (score 1):

You're relying on an internal class from the core libraries. That's an inherently dangerous thing to do as these can change or disappear without prior warning even in between minor releases.

In this case, the class you're relying on extends another class that was deprecated in Java 9 for later removal. This removal most likely happened in Java 17 (though it may have been anywhere post Java 11).

So you had ample warning it was going to disappear. This is not a bug indeed.